# HMACSHA256 проблема с русскими символами C#

Tags: c#, python, python-2.x, хеширование

Добрый вечер,
мне нужно подписать данные (строку) ключом, функцией HMACSHA256
Пользователь сам вводит строку

Когда я подписываю обычные символы, всё ок - в ответе правильный хеш,
если же строка содержит русские символы, то хеш неправильный
Вот код на C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;     
using System.Text;
public class Program
{
     public static void Main()
  {
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII");
    String key = "20f31fbce8c54800bffa5f5d767f2cf142ebcfb87ac4ab76c0c55ba7f1934481";
    String packet;
    Console.WriteLine("Input Data: ");
    packet = Console.ReadLine();
    HMACSHA256 hm = new HMACSHA256(enc.GetBytes(key));
    byte[] result = hm.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(packet));
    String hex = BitConverter.ToString(result);
    hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
    Console.WriteLine(hex.ToLower());
  }
}
```

Есть код на Python 2.7 который правильно подписывает строку с русскими символами

```
import hmac,hashlib
key = '20f31fbce8c54800bffa5f5d767f2cf142ebcfb87ac4ab76c0c55ba7f1934481'
packet= raw_input("Input Data:")
sig = hmac.new(key, packet, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest().encode("hex")
print(sig)
```

Пример, вводим слово: форум

Правильный хеш от python: a6aa8f3d443d7e2592eea7b5c290dbe7d418c8329912b22c2e4e4c0d1ce6a18b

Неправильный от c#: e5a15bb8434e7f0fb6b6ce5e63730a7d119dc14d223ffb5f48a132416948ecdf
Менял различные кодировки, не работает

Нужна помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: ваш код на Питоне зависит от кодировки окружения (консоли например). Чтобы получать переносимый результат, работайте с текстом в Unicode. На Питоне 3, input() сам Unicode возвращает. Чтобы хэш получить текст в байты в фиксированной кодировке превращайте: `input().encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю, какие вы кодировки пробовали, но работает с UTF-8:

```
String key = "20f31fbce8c54800bffa5f5d767f2cf142ebcfb87ac4ab76c0c55ba7f1934481";

HMACSHA256 hm = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
byte[] result = hm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("форум"));
String hex = BitConverter.ToString(result);
Console.WriteLine(hex.Replace("-", ""));
```

Результат:

```
A6AA8F3D443D7E2592EEA7B5C290DBE7D418C8329912B22C2E4E4C0D1CE6A18B
```

Comment: Хм, действительно работает. Спасибо. Но если ввести с консоли, результат совсем другой

Comment: У вас что-то не так, у меня все работает. Посмотрите в дебаге, точно ли у вас кодировка UTF-8. Лучше писать `Encoding.UTF8` чем `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")`

Comment: Я использовал Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes это работает, но не через консоль. Возможно потому-что я использую онлайн компилятор. Вы вводите строку через консоль? Через функцию Console.ReadLine()?

Comment: Да, через консоль.

Comment: Какой компилятор вы используете? И как установить кодировку при вводе в консоли на UTF8?

Comment: VS 2015 .NET 4.6, но я уверен это не имеет значения. Не нужно ничего устанавливать, `packet = Console.ReadLine(); hm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(packet));` это сработает.

Comment: @c0de: В C#, в отличие от C++, кодировка консоли не имеет значения (если только в ней есть символы, которые вы пытаетесь ввести).

Comment: @Zergatul: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)` скорее всего неверно, т. к. `key` похож на 16-ричное число (все символы в [0-9a-f]).

Comment: @VladD автору нужен был такой же хеш, как в питоне, я его и получил